# How can I make sure that every controller sees DboSource?

Tags: cakephp, dependency-injection, cakephp-2.x

There were issues that some controllers are using `DboSource` methods and I added the

```
App::uses('DboSource', 'Model/DboSource');
```

line to the class file of some base controllers from which other controllers are inherited. However, I wonder whether there is a way in Cake to make sure that a class is loaded by every controller. My current solution works, I just intend to improve it. Is this possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this to your `app/Config/bootstrap.php` file and it will be loaded on every request.